# Generating data with Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

We want to generate a Gaussian vector, (call it $\Delta$) - with an arbitrary size-, with zero mean and variance of $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is chosen such that $\parallel\Delta\parallel_2 \leq 0.5$ with probability of e.g. $90\%$.

How can we do that in Matlab?

Comment: Not sure of what you mean by norm(delta, 2). Is delta your mean and 2 your variance, as with the usual notation?

Comment: The problem is in this part, we want a vector whose norm 2 of that be less than or equal to e.g. 0.5 with the specified probability e.g. 90%. I just know that norm 2 of Gaussian has Chi-square distribution!

Answer (score 9):

Let $\Delta = [x_1, \dots, x_N]$ be your desired vector where $x_i$ are iid $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Do you expect that $\mathrm{Pr} \left\lbrace ||\Delta||_2^2 < 0.5\right\rbrace = 0.9$ ?

By definition $y = ||\Delta||_2^2 / \sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_N(y)$ is [Chi squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) of degree of freedom $N$.

Thus $z = ||\Delta||_2^2 = \sigma^2y \sim \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \chi^2_N(\frac{z}{\sigma^2})$

Denote the CDF $\mathrm{F}(z)$, you want something like $\mathrm{F}(z = 0.5) = 0.9$ with $\sigma^2$ is unknown variable.

A closed form expression of $\mathrm{F}(z)$ is available at wikipedia [Chi squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

In MATLAB you can use the two functions `chi2pdf()` and `chi2cdf()` for numerical brute force solution for $\sigma^2$.

And after having the value of $\sigma^2$, just use the function `randn()` to generate your vector $\Delta$. For example with size `N` and $\sigma^2$ = `sigma2`, `delta = randn(1,N) * sqrt(sigma2)`.

Comment: I want Pr { ||Δ||_2<= 0.5} = 0.9 ; In other words the probability that the Euclidean norm of Δ be less than or equal to 0.5 be 90%.

Comment: @RezaMahjoob So just replace 0.5 with 0.25 in the above...

Comment: @RezaMahjoob to clarify what Peter said $\mathrm{Pr \left\lbrace ||\Delta||_2 < 0.25 \right\rbrace} = \mathrm{Pr \left\lbrace ||\Delta||_2^2 < 0.5 \right\rbrace}$

Comment: Sorry; how did you get the distribution of "z" in the last equation? The chi-square argument is not obvious for me.

Comment: @RezaMahjoob $\mathrm{F}_Z(z) = \mathrm{Pr}(Z < z) = \mathrm{Pr}(\sigma^2 y < z) = \mathrm{Pr}(y < z / \sigma^2) = \mathrm{F}_Y(z/\sigma^2)$.

Then $\mathrm{f}_Z(z) = \frac{\mathrm{dF}_Z(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathrm{f}_Y(z/\sigma^2)$.

I did make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab's randn() function generates a vector of zero-mean normally distributed data.

You can proove that if you mutliply a random variable by a constant, then you will mutliply its variance by the square of this constant.

More generally :

$$\begin{split}
\mathrm{Var}[a \times x + b] &= a^2\times\mathrm{Var}[x]\\
\mathrm{Mean}[a \times x + b] &= a\times\mathrm{Mean}[x] + b\\
\end{split}$$

Thus, to generate a random sequence of a specified variance (call it $\sigma_{\Delta}^2$) and 0-mean, you would first generate a 0 mean normally distributed vector with Matlab's `randn()`and then multpily by the square root of you new variance.

Comment: The problem is in this part, we want a vector whose norm 2 of that be less than or equal to e.g. 0.5 with the specified probability e.g. 90%. I just know that norm 2 of Gaussian has Chi-square distribution!